# CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: could not find driver in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii, zend-studio, yii-cactiverecord

while trying to connect with mysql in yii framework it shows

"CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: could not find driver " error

php code :

```
     'db'=>array(
        'class' => 'CDbConnection',
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost:3306;dbname=testdrive',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'root',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),
```

my php drivers are already enabled , but it shows the same error

Im using zend studio, zend server for this

how could i fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Things you should check**

First you should check phpinfo() for the pdo_drivers installed.

if u use IIS server , you should check php extensions installed or not.

check php.ini for extensions_dir is properly given

check you ext folder in php contains pdo_mysql dlls

Some times the problem may occur due to zend server installation .You should check zend server is properly using the php extensions

After that check simple php-mysql connection using the following functions

```
mysql_connect('localhost:3306','root','root');
mysql_select_db('testdrive');
```

If it works then go with Yii, Slim, Zend php-mysql connections

Comment: This answer should probably be updated with the more modern mysqli extension.

Answer (score 9):

I am using Linux Mint..In my case I needed

```
apt-get install php5-mysql
```

because I was moving my environment from Lampp to Apache + PHP + MySQL and I had to change a lot of things in the php.ini

Answer (score 4):

try to install `Sqlite` drive by using following command in Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite php5-sqlite
```

Now restart the Apache server by using following command

```
service apache2 restart
```

this two step solve my problem. hope it will solve other's also...

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Linux Ubuntu.

I have the same problem, but in my case i have to install the php-mysql.

`sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`

and restart the service

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I hope thats help someone

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I also had to enable pdo_sqlite module and this solved the problem. It was on a HOSTiq.com.ua hosting. I suppose it could save someone a few hours on searching.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was this:

```
    cache' => array(
        'class' => 'system.caching.CDbCache',
        //'class' => 'system.caching.CFileCache',
        'connectionID'=>'db', // <<< THIS IS THE ISSUE
    ),
```

if connectionID is not set, db caching defaults to mysqli database in /protected/data directory which cannot be accessed if mysqli driver is not installed on system (common issue with dedicated servers, DO droplets, xampp/wamp...)

or, you can disable db caching and enable fileCache instead.

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of Yii you have a directory **requirements**. It will launch **Yii Requirement Checker** and will show you what is missing.

After that get you connection string right in **main.php**

```
'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=deathstar;port=3306;dbname=database',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'user',
            'password' => 'pass',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_'
),
```

In my case it was something very silly. I forgot **mysql:** in

```
'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=deathstar;port=3306;dbname=database'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't get it only with this

```
apt-get install php-mysql
```

you can try this

```
apt-get install php-pear php5-dev libmysqlclient15-dev
pecl install pdo
pecl install pdo_mysql
```

I've found googling it was the only that works fine for me