# CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection Yii after moving to aws

Tags: mysql, pdo, yii, yii2

I am new into yii. I was transferring a premade yii website to my aws server. After adding the updated database info into protected/config/main.php I am getting this error. None of the references worked. Please help.
Site Url : http://multilingualbabies.com

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/20425029/1138192

Comment: http://multilingualbabies.com/info.php can you please tell me if the configuration is ok or not?

Comment: i can see pdo drive is not enabled

Comment: how to enable it from terminal? I mean what is the command? My php version is 7.2

Comment: check this https://askubuntu.com/a/824505/592341

Comment: ok. pdo drivers are now enabled. anything else in the configuration?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184045/discussion-between-sayantan-das-and-curious-mind).

Answer (score 1):

Possible Issue:

1) PDO driver maybe its not enabled

2) your dsn connection not truth, make sure your configuration somthing like this:

```
return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbName',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'yourPAssword',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

Note: make sure **mysql:** is set in dsn.

3) make sure your mysql port is 3306, if other one try to change dsn by adding port like this `'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;port=portNumber;dbname=dbName',`.

Good Luck

Comment: where to check the db connection?
php info is http://multilingualbabies.com/info.php

Comment: First try to check mysql port please by run this command: `netstat -tlnp`

Comment: if you find port is 3306, then you need to check your username and password, also dbname...

Comment: If I give you the access will you please check once? I am really confused. Not a technical person.

Comment: I would like to help you mate, but without get access to server, its not secure to share sensitive info with others....

Comment: are you used Yii2? advance or basic template?

Comment: I am not sure how to check that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184046/discussion-between-sayantan-das-and-anees-hikmat-abu-hmiad).